# Est-ce que « aurait dû fallu » correspond à l'anglais « should have thought » ?

Tags: anglais, conditionnel

On trouve à la page 87 de *Advanced French Grammar* de Véronique Mazet ce qui suit :

> Il **aurait fallu** qu'elle pense à son livre! = She should have thought about her book!

Cette phrase, est-elle fausse? Est-ce que ça devrait être : 
« Il aurait dû falloir qu'elle pense à son livre » ?

D'après moi :

> Il **aurait fallu** qu'elle pense à son livre! = She would have needed to think about her book.

---

**Un supplément suite à la réponse de Yves et le commentaire de Stéphane Gimenez :**

● Question #1: Pour vouloir dire « On aurait dû avoir besoin de ... », pourquoi est-il défendu d'écrire:

> Il aurait dû falloir que ...?

Yves a écrit qu'« on utilise presque jamais en français "il faut" et "devoir" dans la même phrase. » Pourquoi pas ?

● Question #2: Quels sont des exemples où "il faut" et "devoir" sont employés dans la même phrase ?

Comment: À mon avis comparer l'anglais et le français sur tout ce qui touche à la conjugaison (temps et auxiliaires) est une mauvaise idée. Il n'y a pas de correspondance qui marche dans tous les contextes. Ces deux traductions sont acceptables dans différents contextes. Et en voici une de plus : « *She ought to have thought of it.* »

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux traductions sont bonnes et « *Il aurait dû fallu qu'elle pense à son livre* » est incorrect en français. Voir les « explications ».

- **Voici donc les traductions correctes :**

  > Il aurait fallu qu'elle pense à son livre! *= She should have thought
  >   about her book!*

  Cette traduction est correcte car *falloir* (*aurait fallu*) peut aussi être traduit par *should* (comportement recommandé, politesse)  mais sans contexte « aurait fallu » exprime une nécessité. **La phrase en français implique clairement que la personne ne peut pas faire quelque chose d'important parce qu'elle n'a pas pensé à son livre.** Votre traduction est donc sans doute plus précise en l'absence de contexte :

  > Il aurait fallu qu'elle pense à son livre! *= She would have needed to
  >   think about her book.*
- **La phrase ci-dessous est incorrecte** car il y a falloir et devoir dans la même phrase, et parce que l'un des deux participes (fallu ou dû) devrait être à l'infinitif :

  > Il aurait dû fallu qu'elle pense à son livre *= She would have needed to must think about her book*
- **Mais par contre il est vrai que :**

  > *She should have thought about her book!* = Elle aurait dû penser à son livre!

Ici « elle aurait dû » est moins fort et plus large que « il aurait fallu qu'elle » et correspond mieux à « *she should have* ».

---

**Explications : Le problème ici est l'expression du devoir, de l'obligation, du besoin etc.** En anglais on utilise principalement, selon les cas, les verbes modaux et constructions *need* (pour le besoin), *must* (devoir impératif), *have to* (besoin/devoir moral), *shall/should* (devoir moral / comportement normatif), *ought* (obligation, besoin) pour ne citer que les plus simples.

En français, l'expression de base pour exprimer toutes ces situations est le verbe *devoir* :

> Les musulmans doivent prier cinq fois par jour.
>   *Muslims must pray five times a day*
>
> Pour aller à Paris, tu dois prendre le train.
>   *You need to take a train to travel to Paris.*

Pour éviter de confondre les deux, la **forme impersonnelle du verbe falloir (*il faut que*)** est utilisée pour exprimer le besoin, l'obligation matérielle inévitable. Une des traductions possibles de *falloir* serait « *to be missing* » ou « *to be needed* » (exemple : *il faut encore 20 minutes pour faire ce gateau*).

**Ainsi on utilise presque jamais en français « il faut » et *devoir* dans la même phrase** (ça donnerait en anglais quelque chose comme *have to need*, ce qui n'est pas facile à placer dans une phrase).

---

**Question 2**

"Il faut" et "devoir" peuvent être employés dans la même phrase, si il n'y a pas une redondance complète (sinon ça reste correct mais le sens devient confus et ce n'est pas beau), et donc si les deux ont des sens légèrements différents, ou si l'un est l'objet de l'autre.

Par exemple si "il faut" est l'"action" considérée par, et objet de "devoir" (assez courant en anglais avec must et need) ce qui nécessite une situation bien particulière où les deux ne soient pas complètement répétitifs, par exemple dans cette expression assez courante à l'oral :

> Il **doit bien falloir** un permis poids lourd pour avoir le droit de conduire ce fourgon.

En anglais ça donne quelque chose comme *you must need a truck license to be legally able to drive this vehicle*. Ici devoir exprime un léger doute qui porte sur le besoin (falloir) de posséder le permis en question.

Autre exemple avec "Il faut que" (il faut et devoir ne sont pas dans la même proposition, mais bien dans la même phrase).

Pour reprendre la phrase de la question il est **grammaticalement** correct d'écrire :

> Il aurait dû falloir qu'elle pense à son livre *= She should have needed to  think about her book*

C'est très tordu mais on peut imaginer une situation à la *Inception* ou cela serait correct même si le bon sens voudrait qu'on simplifie pour ne pas donner de mal de tête au lecteur :

Imaginons que *s'il avait fallu* qu'elle pense à prendre son livre elle *aurait dû penser* à aller le chercher à la bibliothèque ce qui lui aurait rappelé son ex-copain libraire et ça l'aurait rendue malheureuse.

Mais comme il *ne fallait pas qu'elle pense* à prendre son livre parce que le professeur avait dit qu'elle n'en avait pas besoin ce jour là, elle *n'a pas dû* penser à son livre, et elle n'a pas pensé à son ex-copain et n'a pas été malheureuse toute la journée. Ainsi pour qu'elle ait été malheureuse ce jour là il *aurait du falloir* qu'elle pense à son livre.

Aspirine quelqu'un ?

Autres exemple possible avec devoir comme traduction de "to owe" en anglais :

> Il faut devoir beaucoup d'argent à quelqu'un pour être mis en prison
>   pour dettes. You must owe a lot of money to someone to be sent to a
>   debtors' prison.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de votre réponse détaillée. SVP, puis-je attirer votre attention sur mon supplément dans mon post original ?

Comment: c'est fait mais il falloir queles lecteurs doivent devoir prendre des comprimés parce que ça devient très long pour pas grand chose...

Comment: Merci mille fois de votre réponse fouillée et supplément utile. Il aurait fallu que je prenne des comprimés si vous n'aviez pas éclairci ma question.

Answer (score 2):

**Il aurait dû fallu qu'elle pense à son livre* n'est pas correct.  Je ne pense pas qu'il soit possible d'utiliser devoir de manière impersonnelle.  *Elle aurait dû penser à son livre* par contre est correct et peut remplacer *Il aurait fallu qu'elle pense à son livre* dans la plupart des contextes sans changer le sens mais en introduisant une ambigüité potentielle : « Elle aurait dû… » est aussi utilisable quand il y a manquement à une obligation tandis qu'avec « il aurait fallu… » sa responsabilité ne peut être aussi fortement mise en cause, on est plus dans le domaine de l'occasion manquée.

Il me semble<sup>*</sup> que *She would have needed to think about her book* est plus proche de *elle aurait eu besoin de penser à son livre* et donc qu'elle aurait personnellement été touchée par son manque de prévoyance (ce qui est possible mais pas obligatoire avec les deux autres formulations).

---

(*) D'une part mon anglais est loin d'être parfait et il est fort possible que des nuances m'échappent, d'autre part de par l'utilisation du conditionnel ce sont des phrases qui supposent un contexte qui n'est pas explicité ici et il est possible que face à un autre contexte que ceux auxquels je pense, mon opinion change.

Comment: Concernant l’impersonnalité et le verbe *devoir*, il doit exister quelques cas :-) Le problème immédiat c'est la succession de deux participes passés. On peut envisager « *il aurait dû falloir* », grammaticalement ce serait acceptable si *falloir* était un verbe normal. Mais ce verbe (ou auxiliaire) est défectif, et la redondance fait que de toute façon cette tournure ne serait pas employée.

Comment: Réponse exacte. "need" exprime le besoin, alors que "devoir" exprime aussi toutes les sortes de... devoirs.

Comment: @StephaneGimenez: Merci de votre correction. Je voulais dire, en fait: « Il aurait dû falloir ». J'ai mis à jour mon post original auquel j'avais ajouté un supplément. Pourriez-vous y diriger votre attention ?

Comment: Je crois que c'est une raison bien plus simple qui rend impossible une phrase commençant par *Il aurait dû fallu*: il n'en pas possible d'avoir un verbe composé avec deux participes passés (nonobstant les verbes surcomposés ou au passif), ce qui est le cas ici. Ce serait comme écrire *She should had thought* en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase de substitution dont vous parlez est :

> Elle aurait dû penser à son livre. (She should have thought about her book.)

Il aurait fallu qu'elle pense à son livre (She would have needed to think about her book) semble être une bonne traduction.

Les sens des deux verbes *falloir* et *devoir* sont assez proches, même si *falloir* semble un peu moins fort, mais :

- il faut partir = we have to leave
- il faudrait partir = we should leave (semble correct néanmoins)

En résumé ce n'est pas vraiment une erreur, on pourrait traduire par « should » ce verbe *falloir*.

Answer (score 0):

Cette phrase est tout à fait correcte. Il aurait "dû falloir" n'existe pas car redondant.
"Il aurait fallu qu'elle pense à son live" ou bien "Elle aurait dû penser à son livre". Cette dernière semble même préférable, une structure impersonnelle ("il aurait fallu") étant ici moins appropriée.